# Finding the equivalent Resistance of acircuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flXvYI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am a little confused on how to find R equivalent of this circuit because of the wire.

Right now I have the following expression:Req=  (R1//R2) +(R3//R4) 
Is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Redrawing the circuit should hopefully make the solution obvious:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frjpeL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So yes, you are correct.